# How to suppress tokens in whisper

Tags: python, openai-whisper

Consider the following decoding script

```py
from transformers import (
        WhisperProcessor,
        WhisperForConditionalGeneration,)

MODEL_NAME="openai/whisper-tiny.en"
processor = WhisperProcessor.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME).to("cuda")


def decode(audio, sampling_rate, **kwargs):
    input_features = processor(
        audio, 
        sampling_rate=sampling_rate, 
        return_tensors="pt"
    ).input_features
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        predicted_ids = model.generate(input_features.to("cuda"), **kwargs)
    transcriptions = [processor.decode(
        predicted_ids_one, skip_special_tokens=True) for
        predicted_ids_one in predicted_ids]
    
    return predicted_ids, [processor.tokenizer._normalize(transcription) 
                for transcription in transcriptions]
```

I was trying to suppress specific tokens from the output

e.g. this would suppress any token with a non-numeric

```py
vocab_to_id = processor.tokenizer.get_vocab()
default_suppressed_tokens = model.generation_config.suppress_tokens
custom_suppressed_tokens = [_id for v,_id in vocab_to_id.items() if not v.isalpha()]
```

e.g the token `23` was suppressed

```py
assert 1954 not in default_suppressed_tokens
assert 1954 in custom_suppressed_tokens
```

but when decoding, both

```py
decode(audio, sr, suppressed_tokens=default_suppressed_tokens)
```

and

```
decode(audio, sr, suppressed_tokens=custom_suppressed_tokens)
```

Give

```txt
(tensor([[50257, 50362,  6288,   338, 17349,   286,  1737,  1160,  1954,    11,
           6208,   278,   352,    13,  1954, 50256]], device='cuda:0'),
 ['today is dance of may 2023 testing one.23'])
```

What is the way to properly restrict the vocabulary when decoding with whisper?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `suppress_tokens` in the `transformers.GenerationConfig` to suppress any token in the vocabulary.

Example line:

`model.config.suppress_tokens = ['token']` will give `-Inf` probability to the `token` word.

`1954` is probably not in the vocabulary, so, you can not suppress it but you might optionally suppress numbers.

For more information, you can see the documentation: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationConfig

Comment: Sorry for scoring down your answer. Read again and try to first understand what I did and improve this answer and I will be happy to accept it.

(1) In your example you set `suppress_tokens` to a `List[str]` the docs show it as a `List[int]`. Adding the reference to the documentation where you found was a positive aspect of your answer, keep doing it whenever you can.

(2) You said that `1954` is probably not in the vocabulary, but in my example `1959` was the logit index associated with the token `23` not a token.

Comment: (2) You suggested me using `model.config.suppress_tokens` instead of passing `suppress_tokens` to `model.generate` without explaining why this would be different, or giving an complete example for me to test.